# Error in Jackson.jar when running proguard in android

Tags: android, jackson, proguard

I have an android project that uses `jackson-all-1.7.2.jar`.

When I run a proguard with this proguard.cfg file:

```
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** {*;}
-keep class org.holoeverywhere.** {*;}

-libraryjars /libs/jackson-all-1.7.2.jar
```

I got this exception:

```
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Note: there were 600 duplicate class definitions.
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider: can't find superclass or interface javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider: can't find superclass or interface javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find superclass or interface javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonParseExceptionMapper: can't find superclass or interface javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.xc.DataHandlerJsonDeserializer$1: can't find superclass or interface javax.activation.DataSource
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.Consumes
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.Produces
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers
.....
.....
.....
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] Warning: there were 387 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-06-15 06:06:04 - ArrowAndroid]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Note, the app running perfectly without proguard.

When I add the following line in proguard.cfg
`-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson`

The app crashes reporting this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PUBLIC_ONLY
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotation(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:260)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.VisibilityChecker$Std.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Are you using inbuilt proguard or another version?

Comment: I use the version bundled with ADT.

Answer (score 5):

The file jackson-all-1.7.2.jar is already in your libs directory, so the Android Ant/Eclipse builds will pick it up automatically. You shouldn't read it again with -libraryjars, because then you'll get these warnings about duplicates.

Jackson is using reflection to find some annotations. ProGuard can't deduce this automatically, and it ends up removing related, seemingly unused fields. This configuration should keep them:

```
-keepclassmembers public final enum org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
    public static final org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I replaced Jackson with Gson

Answer (score 2):

Add these line in your proguard configuration file.

```
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { 
*; 
}
-keepnames interface com.fasterxml.jackson.** { 
    *; 
}
```